# Android: Passing Spinner Selections Across Tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, spinner

I am making an android application with multiple tabs and I followed the developer tutorials that instructed me to make multiple activities. I have spinners on the first tab.

How do I pass the values that are selected by the spinners to the other tabs?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to accomplish this.  You can also take advantage of the [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) to get a callback in other `Activities` whenever a `SharedPreference` is changed anywhere in your application.

Using `SharedPreferences` will **guarantee consistent data** and **persistence**.  From the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

> Modifications to the preferences must
>   go through an SharedPreferences.Editor
>   object to ensure the preference values
>   remain in a consistent state and
>   control when they are committed to
>   storage.

Comment: I have implemented a solution using SharedPreferences. Thank you for the idea and links.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick and dirty solution would be working with a static class, like:

```
public class OptionHelper
{
    private static String option;

    public static void setSelectedOption(String option)
    {
       //...
    }
    public static String getSelectedOption(){
       //...
    }
}
```

Maybe not recommended. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

In my Application I have an Account object that needs to be passed around - I made it `Parcelable`:

https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/account/Account.java#L11

and just add it to the `Intents`

https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TabWidget.java#L83

and in the receivers read it back:

https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/OneTweetActivity.java#L76

Maybe not the best option. But I don't really think the static singletons are best (probably coming from my Appserver background) and the Application is sort of marked as "do not use" in the Android docs, so I don't see an obvious better solution.
Depending on what you do, Preferences usage may also not "scale well".

Comment: Hi, Heiko its interesting to find that Application class is marked as "do not use" in that Android docs.Can u please point  me in the that direction, I couldn't find that.I thought its a way of maintaining application global state.

Comment: "Do not use" is perhaps too hard - if you look at the docs of Application, it says at the top "There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way" - which I read as "don't try this at home kids"